# "class sizes" with Xcode6 for IOS8 is right layout, but IOS7 is not

Tags: ios8, autolayout

The layout is good for IOS8, but for IOS7 seems the right side constraints doesn't work. As below image:

1) why 'N/A' in IOS 7.x screen doesn't layout like iPhone 4-inch screen in the middle. I think the "dao 123 li" label has the same issue.

I think constraints on 'N/A' has no problem, because it lay out on the middle screen is correct.

2) The blue is UITableView's tableHeaderView, why if i set UITableView's leading and trailing space to superview's constrains is '0', there are 16 px distance there.

Here is the constraints on 'N/A'
[image]

Here is the UITableView's constraints.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Then? What do you expect us to help? List out your Auto Layout constraints.

Comment: What constraints you have added on N/A?

Comment: @Raptor  I want to know why ios8 and ios7 layout are different, i think the constraints is correct, because it's IOS8(middle screen) is correct. I attached the constraints on the large 'N/A'

Comment: @AshishP. i Attached the constraints image.

Comment: You need to add constraints by unchecking "constraints to margin". I think you have kept it checked thats why there is 16px padding.

Comment: @AshishP. Thanks, do you know about the first question why?